# Ways to authorize an app only once to run as root

Tags: 13.04, root

I just wrote a small app that modifies a file in the `/sys` directory. Basically, the file `/sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness` is modified to adjust brightness. So it requires root permission. The app is written in C++ and I am using the `system` function to run an echo command (I just wanted the most simple solution). I was wondering If I could authorize the app once and then, whenever it is launched, it runs as root. I don't want the app to request root permission every time it is launched.

EDIT:

```
$ ls -l 
-rwxrwxr-x 1 res res 413934 Jul  6 22:08 BrightnessControl
```

Thanks.

Comment: can you edit your post to show the permissions on the file you need to edit? just want to make sure my answer could work. (Looking for a safer option than letting all programs run as you edit the file but you can still do that if you want)

Comment: @namingFailed Updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6905697/how-to-run-script-as-another-user-without-password   look at the visudo answer
[edit the sudoers file with sudo visudo]

and make it run as root just that file without asking.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Sudoers

Comment: Well, I tried adding something like 'res ALL= NOPASSWD: /path/to/app'  but it doesn't work. The sudo command is inside the app, so, if I keep the sudo, the app requests password and if I remove the sudo, it says permission denied

Comment: is res the group your user is in? youruser ALL=(res) NOPASSWORD: ...

Comment: no, res is the username. Should I be adding a group?

Comment: ok so res is your user. If res is your user then the program shouldn't need root as you have write permissions

Comment: Well, the program is trying to write to the /sys/class/.... directory, so it does need root privileges to do that, right?

Comment: that depends on if you have execute permissions on the directories above the file.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand. the program is in my home directory. The file to be edited is /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness . So, what kind of permissions would I need using this suid method

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I get you wrong, but I think the suid bit is what you need. First, change the owner of the program to root, then

```
chmod +s <filename>
```

it.

By this, it will run with the account of the files owner, no matter which user is starting it.

Comment: But this would require me to start the program as root every time, doesn't it?

Comment: The program would run with root permissions, also if it is started by a regular user. Of course, that user needs the right to run it, so I'd add all users that should be able to use the program to a group, and give the group ownership of the program and execute permission. If all users should be able to run it, you can also give everyone execute permissions.

Comment: A simple doubt, if the SUID bit is set, then a program can modify a system file when executed by a normal user?

Comment: Yes, so one should be careful when setting the suid bit to only apply this setting to trusted applications. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Setuid

Comment: But in my case, when I set the suid bit and run the program, it is saying permission denied for the sudo command